# How can I print via blob in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing, vue-component, blob

I try like this :

```
printBlob () {
    this.$axios.get('/detail/1', {
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log('ok')
      console.log(response.data)
      const file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      window.open(fileURL)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

The result like this :

[image]

And the console log like this :

[image]

There is no data/response from the API

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am confused here. You have said that "_There is no data/response from the API_" but in the console log it is showing the blob data?

Comment: @palaѕн I mean response from API `/detail/1`. I don't find the response

Comment: Not getting what you mean here. You are not getting any response from this API call?

Comment: @palaѕн If I check in network console, there exist response of API. But if I see `console.log(response.data)`, There is no the data of API

Comment: Then how did you get the 2nd image for `console.log(response.data)`?

Comment: @palaѕн  Yeah. I search data from the API in the response, but I did not find it

Comment: @SuccessMan The `response.data` is already be Blob so you don't need to wrap it again. I believe that you can do `window.open(URL.createObjectURL(response.data))`

Comment: @User 28 How do I see data from API? Data to display

Comment: @SuccessMan You can see it on Network tab, select XHR to filter, click on your request, Select Preview/Response. You might see something that unreadable depend on what is your server return.

Comment: @User 28 I know that. I just found a response blob. But I didn't found response to display data in pdf

Comment: @SuccessMan Then you should read about what's Blob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob. If you want display your blob try to `console.log(URL.createObjectURL(response.data))` you will get `blob:http...` then copy url (including blob:) to your browser you will see the response or you can set it to iframe src you should see it either. If you see nothing then maybe because of your server is send something wrong.